# how to Reset Woocommerce earnings without reseting All Woocommerce plugin?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

i created my new store with Woo commerce and when i was checking the pages of websites and checking the payments method (using cash on delivery) i did some orders.

Now when i'm going to my woo commerce dashboard i see in statistics that i did 11 orders and about 1.2 K $ as you know it's just a test.

and i wanted to delete this statistics or reset it to 0 Orders and 0$ ....

Please is there any way to do that .

I'm waiting your answers and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your `Wordpress dashboard-> woocommerce -> orders -> select all the test orders` then select `delete -> after that in the deleted section -> delete permanently`.

This method worked for me.